# HTTP 404 Redirect

Tags: http, seo

We have a multi-tenant web application where customers can set up custom domains for their site.

When an invalid domain is requested we need to display an error page on a different domain. What is the correct way to handle this? I thought perhaps issuing a 303 to a page on the other site that always returns 404. Will this keep search engines happy?

Comment: To clarify what you're trying to achieve: lets say that none of your customers have added www.example.com; if a request is made to your web server to reach www.example.com, you want that request to be automatically redirected to www.example2.com/notfound.htm? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly.

Comment: Does it have to be another domain in the location bar, or would it be sufficient to display a proper error message?

Comment: Why does the error message has to be from a different domain? It was http://example.com/ that was not found, it isn't available elsewhere. Why not just return a 404 immediately?

Answer (score 2):

I am still trying to determine the need for this. As not a lot of information is provided to why its needed. There are many hosts that let users create places for themselves. When any error happens it simply links to the local 404. So why is it needed to go to another domain for 404? As setting a error document 404 with a domain and sub domains. The local 404 is called for all of them. It doesn't just 404 for the main domain, while leaving the sub domains clueless. As for allowing users to set up custom domains I'm guessing that was a typo. And you meant "custom sub domains". Unless that was correct, and its in some way to allow customers to buy hosting packages from you. For which they can sell back to their own customers. If the latter is correct. You would just need to set up their environment correctly. Though I figure you meant sub domain.

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

There are a few better ways to do the below. Just supplying the quickest.
As for wanting to bounce the 404 to another domain you still can:

- In .htaccess do :

  ```
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ```
- In the local 404.html use :

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
  ```

Mind you can use other methods.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to find an application in your control panel on your web host, that will allow you to create an error page. If you're using **cPanel**, this application is named as **Error Pages** which heading with **Advanced** header. After finding this app., now create a file of **404** *(Not found)* error page. In **cPanel**, there are specific *“Referring URL”*, *“Visitor’s IP address”*, *“Requested URL”*, *“Server name”*, *“Visitor’s browser”* and *“Redirect Status Code”* tags for this SSI-enabled file, and after saving 404 error page, it will be saved into `404.shtml` with an extension for a file that recognized by a web server as an SSI-enabled HTML file. If ever there's no *Error Pages* app. in your c-panel, try to create an error page manually with `.shtml` extension if your server is configured to allow this. If it's not allowable or if the file become unreadable, you can still use another extension, but for a web server, it's not recognized as an SSI-enabled HTML file.

The best way is to rewrite and not to redirect all the empty subdomains, into `/404.shtml` but first, make sure that there's a rewrite engine in your account. Now we will going to rewrite all those subdomains with `mod_rewrite`. Try to find a `.htaccess` file in your file manager. That file is often found in the same folder where your `index` page is located. If there's no file like that, you can create a new one in the folder where your `index` located. This code must be at the very top of your empty `.htaccess` source, and DO NOT REMOVE it while testing the following sets of conditions and rules below after this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

And try to paste this directives below the two-lines code above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewrite ^(.*) /404.shtml
```

If the directives above didn't work, then try the following below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
Rewrite ^(.*) /404.shtml
```

However, if you didn't want to redirect those empty subdomains, just add a `[R]` flag after the file extension of the rule, just don't forget a single space before the flag.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the search engines happy, let the 404 appear to be from the invalid domain by Domain masking. This will prevent accumulating poor reputation owing to too many redirects over time. An occasional redirect to canonical document is good as it means you are practicing DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) by redirecting to the canonical IRI qualified for search juice. Use meta noindex on the 404 page to prevent search engines from remembering the invalid custom domain IRIs.